# windows cmd - return first 3 files of a search

Tags: windows-7, command-line

Searching to return the 3 most recently modified files of a particular extension. The search is simple:

```
C:\> dir /od .zip "C:\Users\foobar\Desktop"
```

[Other solutions](https://serverfault.com/questions/490841/how-to-display-the-first-n-lines-of-a-command-output-in-windows-the-equivalent) employ creating temporary .txt files, or querying by use of [other means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) - I'd like to avoid these types of solutions.

If the contents of the directory are (times represent "Modified"):

```
07/16/2014    12:02 PM   1,000,000 file5.zip
07/16/2014    12:01 PM   1,000,000 file4.zip
07/16/2014    12:00 PM   1,000,000 file3.zip
07/16/2014    11:00 AM   1,000,000 file2.zip
07/16/2014    10:00 AM   1,000,000 file1.zip
```

I'd like to see:

```
07/16/2014    12:02 PM   1,000,000 file5.zip
07/16/2014    12:01 PM   1,000,000 file4.zip
07/16/2014    12:00 PM   1,000,000 file3.zip
```

Comment: FTR: The "other means" is really the right tool for the job in Windows 7 and later. PowerShell brings in a *lot* of functionality that CMD just wasn't built for. If your concern is about compatibility with execution policies or limited user permissions across different systems, you can write a helper batch file to bypass most of those issues.

Comment: Also, it seems your screenshot represents output of `dir /o-d` - not `dir /od`. Is that correct?

Comment: Generally, yes. However for my scenario I have some contributing factors that uniquely tailor my search for the specific request. It may be that the output is one or the other, I typed each example from memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usable from CMD or a batch file, and should do what you need on any system running Windows 7 or later:

```
powershell -command "& {dir *.zip | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | select -First 3}"
```

Comment: Was unaware that calling `powershell` from cmd would run (and stay) in cmd, great call